# Django Field Error cannot resolve keyword 'is_staff

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_staff' into field. Choices are: dob, experience, id,user, user_id
```

I get the above error when adding trainer as a Foreign Key to the Subscription model and then accessing any record for Subscription model from admin panel

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(ClientProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(TrainerProfile, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(PaymentHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class TrainerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: add your `TrainerProfile` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access an attribute `is_staff`, which does not exist on the `TrainerProfile` model. `is_staff` is an attribute of `User`, which you reference in your `TrainerProfile` model's `user` field.

In order to access this property, you need to "traverse" the relationship from `Subscription` -> `TrainerProfile` -> `User`. Django allows you to do this by using double-underscore notation, like this: `some_fk_field__fk_field_attribute`.

In your example, you need to change your `limit_choices_to` option on `trainer` to traverse the relationship to the user, like so:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(ClientProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(TrainerProfile, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={'user__is_staff': True})
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(PaymentHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class TrainerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the nested relationship in wrong way

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    # other fields
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(TrainerProfile, null=True, blank=True,
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                limit_choices_to={'user__is_staff': True})
```

That is, it should be **`user__is_staff`** instead of `is_staff`